# module upgrade from joomla 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

i have a module which contain nivo slider in it ...made in joomla 1.5,i have to upgrade in joomla 2.5. I tried but there is always the errror message

```
    Failed loading XML file
    C:\xampp\htdocs\testjoomlasite\tmp\install_50ed4ca94978c\mod_PlimunNivoSlider/mod_PlimunNivoSlider.xml
    XML: Opening and ending tag mismatch: fields line 34 and config
    JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file
```

can someone tell me what all changes are required to upgrade ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  In this case, I think it might help your question to get answered, if you post details of your XML file (more detail is almost always more helpful on SO).  The part about line 34 and ending tag mismatch is a clue that perhaps something is wrong with the xml file which 1.5 was not complaining about, but 2.5 is.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your **xml** setup file of the module like the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Module Title</name>
    .
    .
    <version>2.5</version>
    <description>Module description</description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_test">mod_test.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

Because from `Joomla 1.6` the component setup format has been changed.Instead of using `<install>` tag you can use `<extension>` tag like describe above.